# Can Ya'akov Bond give me a Ktav Kabbalah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

After a pleasant experience with Chicken Kashering in seventh grade (in which we were given chickens who were only shechted, no more, and had to remove the feet, internal organs, etc.), I decided to get a Ktav Kabbalah to be a certified Shochet.

Unfortunately, a google search for 'Shechita license' turned up no first-page results. However, I have heard of someone with such a license to kill-- [Ya'akov Bond](http://www.haaretz.com/jewish/features/the-name-s-bond-ya-akov-bond.premium-1.479770).

Can he give me a ktav kabbalah, or must I continue my search? Does it make a difference if he's [a Spanish Catholic named Santiago](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=james%20spanish%20equivalent)?

### This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I wonder what middle school...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bond actually has several licences to kill. He first tried to get one from a certain doctor, but was told No. He got one from a *rasha*, with love, but of course that's invalid. Then he decided to live and let die rather than do a proper *sh'chita*, so no good *shochet* would give him *kabala*. A poor *shochet* did, but was so ashamed that he told Bond "this *k'sav kabala* is for your eyes only", so Bond couldn't use it anywhere. Next, he studied up on babirusas and got *kabala* from the man from Barbarossa, but it was valid only on those animals. Trying again, he got a *kabala* that allowed him to *shecht* on condition that the animal thrash about all day and die another day; but of course that's useless. So he took a quantum of solace and tried again. Last I heard, he had learned to shoot to kill, which of course is no good at all.

So, yes, you can get *kabala* from him, but it will be severely conditional or hardly accepted. I recommend you try someone else.

Comment: I could be a certified O-Cmon Shochet...